# Jasmine spyOn without hardcoded string

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

Is there an alternative to hardcoding the method name as parameter to spyOn?

I tried to pass foo.name but the test reports the error below.

```
spyOn(foo, 'setBar');

spyOn(foo, foo.name as any);
Error: <spyOn> : () method does not exist
       Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the specified `methodName` is empty, so this implies that `foo.name` is the empty string. `foo.name` must be populated before you call `spyOn()`.

Comment: foo is a function, I try to use the builtin .name field for that function to get the name. What do you mean by populating foo.name?

Comment: By "populating", I mean assign a value to `foo.name`. Given now that `foo` is a function, that suggestion no longer applies. Can you update the question to include a reproducible example (including the definition of `foo`)?